# How to find pattern with Pattern and Matcher classes?

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a program that needs to check where a group of characters exist. My code is currently:

```
String checkerLoop = "ForeclosureResutls_CaseNum_"; 
          Pattern checkerLoopPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<="+Pattern.quote(checkerLoop)+").*?(?="+checkerNumber+")");
          Matcher checkerLoopMatcher = checkerLoopPattern.matcher(scraper.getPage().getWebResponse().getContentAsString()); 

          while (checkerLoopMatcher.find()) {
            checker = true;
          }
```

The sentence I need to look for is "ForeclosureResutls_CaseNum_"+ checkerNumber, where checker number is an int. I tried writing this code based off previous code to find a set of characters in between two groups, so I believe that may be why this code is not working properly.

The sample input string would be as follows:

```
<a id="SheetContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_gvForeclosureResutls_lbCaseNum_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$SheetContentPlaceHolder$ctl00$gvForeclosureResutls$ctl02$lbCaseNum&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">CV-13-798497</a>
                    </td><td align="center">488-05-029</td><td align="center">I</td><td align="center">01/02/2013</td>
        </tr><tr style="background-color:Gainsboro;">
            <td align="left">UNKNOWN HEIRS, ETC OF D.C. RUFUS, ET AL  </td><td align="left">10603 HAMPDEN AVENUE</td><td align="center">CLEVELAND</td><td align="center">44108-0000</td><td align="center">
                        <a id="SheetContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_gvForeclosureResutls_lbCaseNum_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$SheetContentPlaceHolder$ctl00$gvForeclosureResutls$ctl03$lbCaseNum&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">CV-13-798498</a>
                    </td><td align="center">109-16-094</td><td align="center">A</td><td align="center">01/02/2013</td>
        </tr><tr style="background-color:LightGrey;">
            <td align="left">SHARECE MILLER, ET AL  </td><td align="left">13514 ALVIN AVENUE</td><td align="center">GARFIELD HTS</td><td align="center">44105-0000</td><td align="center">
                        <a id="SheetContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_gvForeclosureResutls_lbCaseNum_2" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$Shee
```

Comment: `.*?` is redundant. Change it to `.*`. Why are you using look-behinds and lookaheads? What do you need to do with the data if the term is found? Is the entire line supposed to be searched, as a whole, or are you expecting to find multiple hits per each line? (Your code has `.find()`, which implies multiple hits). I also don't know the overall expected syntax of the line, like is the number supposed to be at the end of the line, or anywhere in the middle?  Hard to help with so much missing context.

Comment: @aliteralmind If the term "ForeclosureResutls_CaseNum_"+checkerNumber is found anywhere in the string, then I just need to go into the while loop stating it has been found and set checker to true. 

I am not sure about how the look-behinds and look-aheads work because I am basing this code off someone who previously wrote a part of it

Comment: What do some example data lines look like? I can't simulate your scraper to try and help you.

Comment: @aliteralmind Added input data string to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so this is what I've got. I'm not fulfilling your requirements exactly, but this should be good to get you on the right path.

First of all `ForeclosureResutls_CaseNum_` is not found at all in this demo data. `ForeclosureResutls_lbCaseNum` is, so that's what I've gone with.

Also, I'm ignoring the `checkerNumber` and assuming you want to check for *any* number, as there are three in this input, and I don't know how yours are derived. Hence the `\\d`.

The regex you were using in your post is crazy, given what you need to do, as far as I understand it. The one I've used is trivial in comparison.

Try this:

```
import  java.util.regex.Matcher;
import  java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
   <P>{@code java ParseForclosureResultsXmpl}</P>
 **/
public class ParseForclosureResultsXmpl  {
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {
      String sLS = System.getProperty("line.separator", "\n");

      StringBuilder sdInput = new StringBuilder().
         append("<a id=\"SheetContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_gvForeclosureResutls_lbCaseNum_0\" href=\"javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$SheetContentPlaceHolder$ctl00$gvForeclosureResutls$ctl02$lbCaseNum&#39;,&#39;&#39;)\" style=\"display:inline-block;width:100px;\">CV-13-798497</a>").append(sLS).
         append("              </td><td align=\"center\">488-05-029</td><td align=\"center\">I</td><td align=\"center\">01/02/2013</td>").append(sLS).
         append("  </tr><tr style=\"background-color:Gainsboro;\">").append(sLS).
         append("      <td align=\"left\">UNKNOWN HEIRS, ETC OF D.C. RUFUS, ET AL  </td><td align=\"left\">10603 HAMPDEN AVENUE</td><td align=\"center\">CLEVELAND</td><td align=\"center\">44108-0000</td><td align=\"center\">").append(sLS).
         append("                  <a id=\"SheetContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_gvForeclosureResutls_lbCaseNum_1\" href=\"javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$SheetContentPlaceHolder$ctl00$gvForeclosureResutls$ctl03$lbCaseNum&#39;,&#39;&#39;)\" style=\"display:inline-block;width:100px;\">CV-13-798498</a>").append(sLS).
         append("              </td><td align=\"center\">109-16-094</td><td align=\"center\">A</td><td align=\"center\">01/02/2013</td>").append(sLS).
         append("  </tr><tr style=\"background-color:LightGrey;\">").append(sLS).
         append("      <td align=\"left\">SHARECE MILLER, ET AL  </td><td align=\"left\">13514 ALVIN AVENUE</td><td align=\"center\">GARFIELD HTS</td><td align=\"center\">44105-0000</td><td align=\"center\">").append(sLS).
         append("                  <a id=\"SheetContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_gvForeclosureResutls_lbCaseNum_2\" href=\"javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$Shee").append(sLS);

      String sRqdValuePrefix = "ForeclosureResutls_lbCaseNum_";
      Pattern checkerLoopPattern = Pattern.compile(sRqdValuePrefix + "\\d");
      Matcher m = checkerLoopPattern.matcher("");  //Unused. so the matcher can be reused in the loop.

      int iLn = 0;
      String[] asInput = sdInput.toString().split(sLS);
      for(String s : asInput)  {
         iLn++;    //1st iteration: Was zero, now 1

         //Resuing matcher instead of retrieving new one from Pattern each iteration
         m.reset(s);

         if(m.find())  {
            int iCheckerNumber = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(m.start() + sRqdValuePrefix.length(), m.end()));
            System.out.println("Found on line " + iLn + ", at index " + m.start() + " with checker number " + iCheckerNumber);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java ParseForclosureResultsXmpl
Found on line 1, at index 39 with checker number 0
Found on line 5, at index 57 with checker number 1
Found on line 9, at index 57 with checker number 2
```

Ask any questions.